# Bash script to check mutliple ips with nc and grab HEADER information

Tags: bash

I am completely new to programming and having a little trouble trying to find how to write a script for `netcat` to do

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
```

checking on port 80 for multiple ip addresses. Can anyone please assist in making a bash script that can connect to multiple ips using this commands.

```
nc -v 192.x.x.x 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
(GRAB THE INFORMATION HERE)
```

disconnect and move on to the next ip address

Answer (score 0):

try doing this using [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
declare -A array
for i in 192.168.0.{1..10}; do
    array["$i"]="$(
        printf '%s\n\n' 'HEAD / HTTP/1.0' | nc -w1 $i 80
    )"
done
```

list of array keys :

```
printf '%s\n' "${!array[@]}"
```

array values

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

iterating through the array :

```
for ip in "${!array[@]}"; do
    # "something with ${array[$ip]} or $ip"
done
```

---

If you don't have [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4), simply use a traditional array with

```
for i in {1..10}; do ...
```